# How to add a new html page to my react outlook add-in

Tags: reactjs, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created a new outlook add-in using the react-taskpane option in the yeoman generator.
I need to insert a new html page to prompt it when there's no signed user is present.

This is the file structure:

[image]

I didn't change the manifest file. But, I included the following in the webpackconfig.js file:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: "Handler.html",
    template: "./src/AppCommon/Auth/Handler.html",
    chunks: ["Handler"],
  }),
```

When I run ***npm run build*** Handler.html gets included in the dist folder.
How can I prompt that page in a separate window? (The logic to check whether the user is logged in or not is not needed).

I used this line for that:

```
window.location.href = app.hostUrl + "/src/AppCommon/Auth/Handler.html";
```

And I'm getting this error:
**Cannot GET /src/AppCommon/Auth/Handler.html**

How can I define the path correctly?? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want a separate window, don't use window.location.href. Use the `Office.UI.displayDialogAsync` method. For more details, see the official documentation: [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

Secondly, I don't think you should have the `/src` in the URL, especially if you are in production mode and serving the file from `/dist`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve it :) Do you also know how I can include an entire folder in the dist folder? I need to include a folder named as WEB-INF inside the dist folder when I run "npm run build" how can I do that? Inside the WEB-INF folder there is a web.xml and a weblogic.xml file

Comment: That's something you configure in webpack. I believe you use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Yes, Thank you! I figured it out :)